# Mixing Absolute Positioning, Relative Positioning of DIVS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay, I want to achieve the following effect

I have two divs that should be on top of each other. I have a third div that should be directly under the two divs. The first two divs can toggle visibility so that when one is visible, the other is not (note: I removed the toggle on part in the javascript to simplify the troubleshooting). But regardless, the third div should be below the other two. Sounded simple a couple hours ago, but I am missing something and would appreciate your help.

I created a paired down HTML file with only the important parts for you to review and hopefully show me what I am misunderstanding.

Also note that I really don't want to use a top property on div3 as it is possible that I might want to dynamically change the size of the first two divs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
        function clicked(t) {
            t.style.visibility = "collapse";
            t.style.opacity = 0.0;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="divone" class="one" onclick="clicked(this)"></div>
        <div id="divtwo" class="two" onclick="clicked(this)"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
    </div>

    <style>
        div {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            transition-duration: 2s;
        }

            div.container {
                width: 50%;
                top: 0;
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                border-left: 0px;
                border-top: 0px;
                padding-left: 0px;
                padding-top: 0px;
            }

            div.one {
                position: absolute;
                background-color: red;
                width: 50%;
                opacity: 1.0;
                z-index:2;
            }

            div.two {
                position: absolute;
                background-color: green;
                width: 50%;

                opacity: 1.0;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            div.three {
                position: relative;
                top: 0;
                width: 60%;
                background-color: blue;
            }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Need a better description of what is supposed to happen. When I click on it, I get two changes of state.

Comment: Yup, you are seeing each of the first two divs disappear. Once both disappear, I want the third div to move up to fill in the space. this isn't exactly what I am looking to do, but if I understand this more simplified case, I can get to what I really want to do.

Comment: But I do see the third div in the end.

Comment: "I want the third div to move up to fill in the space." If this is unclear, I will try to explain another way: The first two divs take up 100px. I want the third div to move up 100px if the first two are collapsed.

Comment: I'm saying that is what I see. It's 100px tall but not as wide as the other two and takes up the same space as the other two divs.

Comment: That is very odd. I will check this out on another browser and see what I see. I am stuck on a box with only IE 11 and the third div stays stationary no matter what I do.

Comment: Never, EVER use IE as a reference for how things should work. I was using Chrome. It works the same in Firefox.

Comment: I am trying it in Chrome, same behavior. The Blue box does not move up once the other two divs disappear.

Comment: By "move up" do you mean slide up from a lower position into this one?

Comment: Is visibility collapse not a table property? .. It does not work on a div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <style>

        div {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            transition-duration: 2s;
        }

        div.container {
            width: 50%;
            top: 0;
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            border-left: 0px;
            border-top: 0px;
            padding-left: 0px;
            padding-top: 0px;
        }

        div.one {
            background-color: red;
            width: 50%;
        }

        div.two {
            background-color: green;
            width: 50%;
            display:none;
        }

        div.three {
            width: 50%;
            background-color: blue;
        }

    </style>

    <script>
        function clicked(t) {
            t.style.display = "none";

            if (t.id === 'divone') {
                document.getElementById('divtwo').style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('divone').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="divone" class="one" onclick="clicked(this)">DIV 1</div>
        <div id="divtwo" class="two" onclick="clicked(this)">DIV 2</div>
        <div class="three">DIV3</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I am looking for. I changed your code a bit to allow for both div 1 and 2 to disappear and div 3 move appropriately. I voted this as the correct answer and would vote it up but don't have enough reputation yet... So it appears that it is the display:  'block' is what I was missing?

Comment: You used absolute positionning but you want static positionnning. this was the main problem. Check the differences in the CSS code.